# C++ , Windows programming

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out a thing and it's killing me that i don't find how to do it .

I got a code in which if `VK_RETURN` is pressed a plane explodes .
The thing is i want the computer to do the instructions that the `VK_RETURN` does if a specific condition is met , let's say i got

```
if (calculus == calculus2)
```

and if that condition is satisfied i want the system to do the things that it usually does when i press the `RETURN` key .
Is there any way to make the computer " press " the return key ?

Thanks !

Comment: where do you want the return key sent?

Comment: Move the code that the return key executes out to a separate function that you can call. Call that function when the return key is pressed, or when the condition is satisfied and you want the code to run without the return key being pressed.

Comment: Take a look at the SendInput API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Yes guys , i need the return key sent .. im gonna take a look at the sendinput api ,moving the code alters the algorithm , it doesent work because i have to make some global variables which i dont wanna use , the thing im working on is a game like raptors  , its almosts complete .

Comment: Edit your question, don't post other informations as answers. Stackoverflow doesn't work like a classic discussion forum.